# Рекурсивные вызовы в qucksort

Tags: c, сортировка

Не понимаю, как происходят рекурсивные вызовы для сортировки подмассивов 
Происходит ли это так ? : вызывается рекурсивная функция и она остается не доделанной , и вызывается следующая до тех пор , пока эти вызовы не закончатся , а потом возвращаемся на предыдущие уровни рекурсии доделывать предыдущие вызовы ?
Так ли это ? Если нет, то в каких случаях подобное происходит. И как тогда работает рекурсия в qsort ?
  Вот код , где рекурсивная функция , про которую спросил выше

```
template<class T>
void quickSortR(T* a, long N) {
// На входе - массив a[], a[N] - его последний элемент.

  long i = 0, j = N-1;      // поставить указатели на исходные места
  T temp, p;

  p = a[ N>>1 ];        // центральный элемент

  // процедура разделения
  do {
    while ( a[i] < p ) i++;
    while ( a[j] > p ) j--;

    if (i <= j) {
      temp = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = temp;
      i++; j--;
    }
  } while ( i<=j );


  // рекурсивные вызовы, если есть, что сортировать 
  if ( j > 0 ) quickSortR(a, j);
  if ( N > i ) quickSortR(a+i, N-i);
}
```

Comment: "Так ли это ?" - да, это так.

Comment: Рекурсия тем и удобна, что "остается недоделанной", то есть сохраняется промежуточное состояние.

Comment: То есть я правильно понимаю, что любая рекурсия так(как я написал в вопросе) действует ?

Comment: @Elvin  да, это так.

Comment: @Igor, почему-то когда вручную прогонял алгоритм рекурсивные вызовы не заканчивались и соответственно возврата на предыдущие уровни рекурсии не было , поэтому вопрос и задал

Comment: За "пионэрство" типа `N>>1` надо бить по рукам.

Comment: @AnT, да , я теперь с того раза уже(как вы объяснили ) медиану трёх использую , тут просто проще было код с алголиста скопировать , чтобы про рекурсию спросить

Comment: Дело не в "медиане трех", а в том, что если вы хотите `N` разделить на `2`, то так и следует писать: `N / 2`.

Comment: @Elvin `почему-то когда вручную прогонял алгоритм рекурсивные вызовы не заканчивались и соответственно возврата на предыдущие уровни рекурсии не было , поэтому вопрос и задал` значит ли это, что в сущности ваш вопрос звучит так: "Почему алгоритм завершается?"